# PowerShell -eq operator dont return true for date comparison i Azure Function

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I am using [SharePoint PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/readme.md) to retrieve list items from a SharePoint list. The next thing I want to do is to compare two dates. A date from the received item against today's date. This code works on my local machine. But when I run it on my Azure Function it doesn't return the dates as equal. It doesn't return any errors either.It jsut runs past the if. The code works when I debug it in PowerShell ISE.

```
ForEach ($ListItem in $ListItems){

    $title = $ListItem["Title"]
    $today = [DateTime]::Today
    $notificationDate = $ListItem[$QMSREVISIONDATE].ToLocalTime().Date

  if ($notificationDate -eq $today){
     $lookUpFieldId = $ListItem[$QMSRESPONSIBLE].LookupId
     $lookUpFieldTypeId = $ListItem[$QMSRESPONSIBLE].TypeId

    try{
        $ListItems2 = (Get-PnPListItem -List "ProcessRoles" -Id $lookUpFieldId -Fields $QMSEMAIL).FieldValues

        }
        catch{
        }

        ForEach ($ListItem2 in $ListItems2){
            $responsibleEmail = $ListItem2[$QMSEMAIL]

            $emailBody = "some text"
            $emailSubject = ("{0}{1}" -f "Dokument: ", $title)

            try{
                Send-PnPMail -To $responsibleEmail -Subject $emailSubject -Body $emailBody
            }
            catch{

            }

            }

    }

}
```

> EDIT

```
2018-02-20T09:21:53.688 [Info] 2/19/2018 12:00:00 AM <--This date should be  2/20/2018
2018-02-20T09:21:53.688 [Info] -eq
2018-02-20T09:21:53.688 [Info] 2/20/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

Isn't the code suppose to detect the  `.ToLocalTime().Date`. Depends on where the Azure server is located I guess?

> EDIT 2

When i run `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones()` in the Azure function I get a list of all the supported timeZones. Stockholm is in there. My question now is how do I convert my `$ListItem[$QMSREVISIONDATE].ToLocalTime().Date` which is UTC to Stockholm local time?

Comment: Why don't you convert both values `.ToUniversalTime().Date`?

Comment: Nope. didnt work. still showing up as diffrent dates

Comment: I dont get it. Your solution works in ISE, but in azure I still get diffrent dates.

Comment: Why not convert your dates to UTC instead?

Comment: Hmm. I’ll try it out.

Comment: Tried it and I dont get it: I used `[DateTime]::UtcNow.Date` and I get `21 februari 2018 00:00:00` SharePoint returns UTC date and that is 20/02/2018. Why is `[DateTime]::UtcNow.Date` returning UTC +1?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a timezone issue with things like this. You can set your time zone on Azure Funcionts via the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` setting.

You can see this blog post for more detailed background: https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2017/01/24/changing-the-timezone-on-your-azure-webapp-app-service-function/

Comment: No luck unfortunately